# Interesting algorithm challenge of converting a array of 1D matrices into a master 1D matrix, need efficient solution

Tags: c++, algorithm

two typedefs

```
std::vector<double> Matrix;
std::vector<Matrix> MatrixBlocks;
```

The Matrix is represented by a 1D vector, and the MatrixBlocks represents a vector of matrix.

The problem is that given that matrix blocks which contains sub matrices from a larger matrix with a specific ordering, I need to reconstruct the large matrix with the matrix block. So For example

Assume the Large Matrix( stored as `std::vector<double>` ) has the following data:

```
 1  2  3  4 
 5  6  7  8
 9  10 11 12
 13 14 15 16
```

and the MatrixBlocks below which contains the sub matrices of the above matrix has the following data:

index 0:

```
1 2
5 6
```

index 1:

```
3 4 
7 8
```

index 2:

```
9 10 
13 14
```

index 3:

```
11 12 
15 16
```

So given that MatrixBlock I need to reconstruct the original vector of double; 1D matrix. Anyone got any general solution?

You can assume that if the large Matrix is always a square sized matrix.

EDIT:

For NxN matrix, that gets broken down to K mxm matrix where N is divisible for m, you can assume that the ordering of the MatrixBlock as so:

index 0: will contain the matrix starting from [0,0] to (m,m)

index 1: will contain the matrix starting from [0,m] to (m, m + m)

index 2: will contain the matrix starting from [0,m+m] to (m, m + m + m)

...

until the last index will contain the matrix starting from [m*i - m,m*i - m] to [m,m]

So for example if the Master matrix is 512x512

```
1 2 3 4 ... 512
513 ...   1014
 ...
```

261632(512*512-512) ... 262144(512*512)

and we wanted to split the 512x512 matrix int 256 32x32 blocks, the 32 is picked by the user, then the MatrixBlock would contain something like

index 0:
   1 2 3 ... 32
   513 ... 513 + 32
   //..up to the first 32 rows of column length 32

index 1:
 33 34 ... (33+32)
 (513+32+1) ... (513 + 32 + 1 + 32)
 //... same as above

So you can see that it starts from index (0,0) and extracts the first 32x32 element from (0,0) to (31,31); thats for index 0.  Then for index 1, the starting position is (0,32) and it extracts data from the rectangle (0,32),(0,63), (31,32), (31,63)

Hope that is clear. So basically the same pattern observed for the 4x4 matrix above, will be the same pattern for any matrix size, the only difference is that the Master matrix is not always of size 4x4, and the block size we split it into is not always 2x2.

Comment: In the general case, how would the program know that it had to break the 4x4 (or N x N) matrix down into a specific pattern of sub-matrices?

Comment: good question, I have reedited the question to answer it

Comment: IMO it's confusing to talk about "1D vectors": you mean 1D arrays, represented as singly-layered `std::vector`s, not vectors in a 1-dimensional vector space (those would be simple `double`s). A vector has always just one index dimension. "1D Matrix" analogous.

Comment: Yes sorry, C++ and math terminology are getting tangled up. Title changed

Comment: Can we change the data structure from a `vector` of `vector` to a single `vector`?  For example a 4x4 matrix would be represented as a 1d `vector` of length 16.  This would simplify the addressing formulas.

Comment: The master matrix should be represented as a vector of double, so for that 4x4 matrix it should be a vector of length 16. The vector of vector is just to contain the array of sub matrices which needs to be converted into the master matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically boils down to indexing correctly.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> v(16);
  std::vector<std::vector<double> > m;
  std::vector<double> m1 {1,2,5,6};
  m.push_back(m1);
  std::vector<double> m2 {3,4,7,8};
  m.push_back(m2);
  std::vector<double> m3 {9,10,13,14};
  m.push_back(m3);
  std::vector<double> m4 {11,12,15,16};
  m.push_back(m4);

  size_t idx = 0;
  for (size_t big_row = 0; big_row < std::sqrt(m.size()); ++big_row)
  for (size_t small_row = 0; small_row < std::sqrt(m1.size()); ++small_row)
  for (size_t big_col = 0; big_col < std::sqrt(m.size()); ++big_col)
  for (size_t small_col = 0; small_col < std::sqrt(m1.size()); ++small_col)
  {
    v[idx] = m[big_col + std::sqrt(m.size()) * big_row][small_col + std::sqrt(m1.size()) * small_row];
    ++idx;
  }

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the original matrix is big NxN, and each sub-matrix is nxn. The number of sub-matrices to a side is then (N / n); let's call that k.

We can think of the big matrix, then, as a long, n*k*n*k-length list.

We can map the big matrix index to sub-matrix number and index, or vice versa. The forward mapping seems super-convoluted, and I only figured it about by first writing out the sub-matrix index I want as a series, then write a function to generate that series (and the time-test trial-and-error method, of course).

Some code demonstrating the first method (please pardon the dust):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  // Initialize the Vector and Set up the Matrices
  std::vector<double> v(36);
  std::vector<std::vector<double> > m;
  std::vector<double> m1 {1,2,7,8};
  m.push_back(m1);
  std::vector<double> m2 {3,4,9,10};
  m.push_back(m2);
  std::vector<double> m3 {5,6,11,12};
  m.push_back(m3);
  std::vector<double> m4 {13,14,19,20};
  m.push_back(m4);
  std::vector<double> m5 {15,16,21,22};
  m.push_back(m5);
  std::vector<double> m6 {17,18,23,24};
  m.push_back(m6);
  std::vector<double> m7 {25,26,31,32};
  m.push_back(m7);
  std::vector<double> m8 {27,28,33,34};
  m.push_back(m8);
  std::vector<double> m9 {29,30,35,36};
  m.push_back(m9);

  // These variables (see explanation above) take on these values for this example
  unsigned N = 6;
  unsigned n = 2;
  unsigned k = N/n;

  // Constructing the Big Matrix    
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < N*N; ++i) {
    int a = (i / (n * k * n)) * k + ((i / n) % k);
    int b = (i % (n * k * n)) % n + ((i % (n * k * n)) / (n * k) * n);
    v[i] = m[a][b];
    std::cout << a << "\t" << b << "\t" << v[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

We can also work with a reverse mapping by traversing the list of sub-matrices and map each index back to the big matrix. I haven't coded that yet, but you get the idea.

Either way, the algorithm should take O(N^2) time in all cases (with N being the side of the big matrix). If you let N be the size of the of matrix, then it's linear time.

Is that efficient enough for your application?